# Facebook open graph in meta tags

Tags: facebook, html

```
<meta property="og:title">
<meta property="og:description">
<meta property="og:image">
```

What is the purpose of using Facebook Open Graph in Website's Meta tags?
What does it add to the website?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't add anything to your website per say, but if someone share your website (or like it now) you can decide to specify the image and description displayed.

Otherwise Facebook let the user decide which image to use or decide automatically.

So depending on your content, it might be better to force Facebook to use the image you want to share.